# How should I split a LSF string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Suppose I have following LSF:

```
873411_ExtraNode -q lnx64 -P someprog:98.90:PV:DY -W 90:08 -R "rusage[mem=5000] select[(OSME==Linux) && ( (OEL==EV70&&SFIPLATFORM>=c0896)||(OEL==EG70&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0298)||(OEL==SHGS12&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0298)||(OEL==SHGS11&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0290))]"
```

What I want is to split this in a way so that I can get a JSON or dictionary of all the switches (as keys) along with the values.The first alphanumeric word is also a value to "name" key. 
Also there should be internal split on each attribute passed to rusage.

I am not to able to form such a complex regex and splitting this value at every point seems a very un-pythonic way to code.

Expected Output:

lsf =

```
{ "name" : "873411_ExtraNode",

 "-q" : "lnx64",
 "-P" : "someprog:98.90:PV:DY",
 "-W" : "90:08",
 "-R" : "rusage"
 "rusage" :[
   {
       "mem" : "5000",
       "OSME" : "Linux",
       "OEL" : "EV70, EG70, SHGS12, SHGS11",
       "SFIPLATFORM" : ">=c0896, d0298, d0298, d0290"
   }
]
}
```

Any leads is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide expected output.

Comment: @andrew_reece did it.

Comment: Is `rusage` meant to be a dict key?

Comment: yes, along with subkeys (if possible in some data structure) mem, OSME, etc.

Comment: In that case please format your code correctly.

Comment: but that is the format which I  will read from a text file.

Comment: I mean format your expected *output* correctly.  Currently `rusage` is written as a variable, not as the key to a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your string from example with `shlex.split` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split)), regular expression is not necessary:

```
import shlex
from pprint import pprint

s = '''873411_ExtraNode -q lnx64 -P someprog:98.90:PV:DY -W 90:08 -R "rusage[mem=5000] select[(OSME==Linux) && ( (OEL==EV70&&SFIPLATFORM>=c0896)||(OEL==EG70&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0298)||(OEL==SHGS12&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0298)||(OEL==SHGS11&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0290))]"'''

l = shlex.split(s)
d = {switch:value for switch, value in zip(l[1::2], l[2::2])}
d['name'] = l[0]
pprint(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'-P': 'someprog:98.90:PV:DY',
 '-R': 'rusage[mem=5000] select[(OSME==Linux) && ( '
       '(OEL==EV70&&SFIPLATFORM>=c0896)||(OEL==EG70&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0298)||(OEL==SHGS12&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0298)||(OEL==SHGS11&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0290))]',
 '-W': '90:08',
 '-q': 'lnx64',
 'name': '873411_ExtraNode'}
```

EDIT:

To parse `-R` parameter, you can use `re`. ([explanation of regex here](https://regex101.com/r/SAFlUg/1)).

```
import shlex
import re
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

s = '''873411_ExtraNode -q lnx64 -P someprog:98.90:PV:DY -W 90:08 -R "rusage[mem=5000] select[(OSME==Linux) && ( (OEL==EV70&&SFIPLATFORM>=c0896)||(OEL==EG70&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0298)||(OEL==SHGS12&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0298)||(OEL==SHGS11&&SFIPLATFORM>=d0290))]"'''

def parse_r(s):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    groups = re.finditer(r'rusage.*?(?P<rusage>\d+)|OSME.*?(?P<osme>\w+)|OEL.*?(?P<oel>\w+)|SFIPLATFORM.*?(?P<sfiplatform>[<>=\w]+)', s)
    for g in groups:
        for k, v in g.groupdict().items():
            if not v:
                continue
            d[k] += [v]
    return d

l = shlex.split(s)
d = OrderedDict(( (switch, value) for switch, value in zip(l[1::2], l[2::2]) ))
d['name'] = l[0]
d['-R'] = parse_r(d['-R'])
pprint(d)
```

Prints:

```
OrderedDict([('-q', 'lnx64'),
             ('-P', 'someprog:98.90:PV:DY'),
             ('-W', '90:08'),
             ('-R',
              defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
                          {'oel': ['EV70', 'EG70', 'SHGS12', 'SHGS11'],
                           'osme': ['Linux'],
                           'rusage': ['5000'],
                           'sfiplatform': ['>=c0896',
                                           '>=d0298',
                                           '>=d0298',
                                           '>=d0290']})),
             ('name', '873411_ExtraNode')])
```

Comment: that's nifty. but two things, order isn't the same also can I further break rusage data. I have update the question with expected output. Kindly check.